# How to get taxonomy image attached to a Post Type WordPress

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type and attached it to a Custom Taxonomy. I used Advanced Custom Fields to add an image upload option to taxonomy.

But I can't retrieve image in Front End. I used below code to get the image URL. But it is not working.

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo get_post_meta(get_ani_taxonomy_fields($ani->term_id, 'acf_image_field_name'), '_wp_attached_file', true); ?>" />
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please let me know name of"custom post type", "taxonomy" and "acf image field" so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

> use this snippet
>   here i get image which have post id 5

```
<img src='<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo get_post_meta(5,'_wp_attached_file',true); ?>' height="100" width="100">
```

> check get_ani_taxonomy_fields($ani->term_id, 'acf_image_field_name') this function return post id

Comment: Tried. But same issue still there. :(

Comment: Serach in your wp_postmeta table by post id and  _wp_attached_file meta key what you get in meta value.